# How to call a Javascript function from inside a Jquery on some event like clicking of a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where I show some text. I want to hide that text and show it only when someone clicks a link/button. I tried using this:

```
<script>
    function f()
    {          
      document.getElementById("line").focus();
      document.getElementById("help").innerHTML = helptext();
    }

    $(function(){
       $('p[id=help]').hide();
       $('a[title=showcmd]').click(function(){
            $('p[id=help]').slideIn();
            $(this).hide();
            f();
       });
    });

    </script>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Yes. I just forgot to add that. Now you can check. I have edited the question.

Comment: Are you sure your listener is called?

Comment: Looks fine to me... is `helptext` defined anywhere? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Yes. It is defined. And it is rendering well if I just call the function on body load.

Comment: What does the Console say?

Comment: Mind adding a ; to the end of f() definition, just in case

Comment: @Meta this seems useless to me.

Comment: Try $("#help") as the selector instead of $("p[id=help]"). That might help.

Comment: As @dystroy hinted at, `slideIn` is not standard jQuery. I guess the code errors there (the console will tell you).

Comment: In a JSFiddle, it is an error. With jQuery 1.8.2: http://jsfiddle.net/11684/zrRHu/

Comment: This is the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LFpqm/

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slideIn' "

Comment: @Meta Function f() is not a jquery function.

Comment: @dystroy In my other page slideIn is working fine.

Comment: @palakmathur if you change the Library you're using to jQuery 1.8.2 instead of MooTools, you'll get this: http://jsfiddle.net/11684/LFpqm/7/ and the error I and dystroy already found.

Comment: @palakmathur Could you show us the code of that 'other page'? Are you sure you don't mean `.fadeIn()`?

Comment: Or maybe you were using a plugin that you don't import here. But I'm sure there is no slideIn in standard jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the console shows](http://jsfiddle.net/WQcv7/), there is no `slideIn` function in jQuery :

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slideIn'

**tested code :**

```
function f()
    {          
      document.getElementById("help").innerHTML = "Trying out Jquery";
    }

$(function(){
   $('p[id=help]').hide();
   $('a[title=showcmd]').click(function(){
        $('p[id=help]').slideIn();
        $(this).hide();
       f();
   });
});
```

I suppose you wanted to use [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) or [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), or maybe [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).

For future problems, I'd suggest you to look at the [developer console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) : it always shows the error message, most often in a clear enough way with the exact location in your code.

Comment: I think I was using the wrong function. But still when I am using .fadeIn(), it is still not working on my page though on fiddlejs it is working.
Thank you for immense help.

Comment: Hi All, 

 It is working now. Some problem with cache was preventing from the changes to load. 

 Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
$('p[id=help]').slideIn();
```

To

```
$('p[id=help]').slideDown();
```

There's no slideIn in jquery

Answer (score 1):

If its not work then try to prevent the click event as below.

```
<script>
    function f()
    {          
      document.getElementById("line").focus();
      document.getElementById("help").innerHTML = helptext();
    }

    $(function(){
       $('p#help').hide();
       $('a[title=showcmd]').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('p#help').slideDown('slow');
            $(this).hide();
            f();
       });
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `slideDown()` instead of `slideIn()`